# navigate between two listview with slide motion in jQuery mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

is it possible to navigate between two listview or even two view which has its own listview inside with **slide** motion in jQuery mobile, now as i implement the first sample when i click on a listview it does not have any motion, it just refresh and the other view come to browser. my purpose is to navigate between two view as like as native ios application which second view slide into first view from right to left.

is this possible with jQuery mobile?

thanks

Comment: Are you using nested listview? add `data-transition="slide"` to anchor tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### solution without changing pages

if you don't want to change your page, a possible solution would be to wrap each listview in a swipable `<div />`.

There are some plugins out there like:

- http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library
- http://www.idangero.us/sliders/

### solution with changing pages

If you're looking for standard page-transitions, take a look @

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

`data-transition="slide"` like @Omar said would fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<li data-transition="slide"></li>
```